# ArrayList display with Java Thread

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, service, java-threads

server code :

```
public class server {
//private static ArrayList<user> t = new ArrayList<>();
public static  Socket s = null;
public static ServerSocket ss = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
         ss = new ServerSocket(1777);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("waiting for connexion");
             s = ss.accept();
           System.out.println("connected with "+s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);
            String username = br.readLine();             
            int number = 0;
            user us = new user(s,number,username);
            //t.add(us);
            pw.print(us);
           //new service(s,username,number,t).start();
           new service(s,us).start();
            number++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());                        
    }
} 
}
```

service class code :

```
public class service extends Thread {
private static Socket s;
private static String user;
private  static int number ; 
private  ArrayList<user> locallist = new ArrayList<user>();
private static user us;

public service(Socket s,user u){
    this.s = s;
    this.us = u;
    locallist.add(u);
}
@Override
public void run() {
    int listsize = locallist.size();
     user lastuser = locallist.get(listsize-1);
    try {
        while (true) {
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);
            System.out.println("last user : " + lastuser);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    
}
```

client class code :

```
public class client {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        while (true) {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",1777);
        System.out.println("connected with localhost");
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);
        Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter you username to continue");
        String username = e.next();
        pw.println(username);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

the server output :

```
waiting for connexion
connected with /127.0.0.1:51899
waiting for connexion
connected with /127.0.0.1:51902
last user : username teste usernumber 0
last user : username teste usernumber 0
last user : username teste usernumber 0
```

basically infinit loop

the client output :

```
connected with localhost
enter you username to continue
teste
connected with localhost
enter you username to continue
```

my question is how can i stop the infinit loop and display the last connected/added member after each client connection

Answer (score 0):

in the server class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(1777);

        int number = 0; // <--- place the counter here not in the while
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("waiting for connexion");
            s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("connected with "+s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);
            String username = br.readLine();
            //int number = 0; // Not here ... you just set the counter always to 0
            user us = new user(s,number,username);
            pw.print(us);
            new service(s,us).start();
            number++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

in the service class:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int listsize = locallist.size();
    user lastuser = locallist.get(listsize-1);
    try {
        // while(true) { // <--- should be removed
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);
        System.out.println("last user : " + lastuser);
        // } <--- while-end
        // <--- for later use?
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

so that is the finished code ... you just had to remove the while in the service-class, move the declaration of the counter-variable "number" out of the while in the server-class.

If you want to use the while in the service-class later for communication between server and client you just have to place a while after you printed the user out.

Comment: if i just remove the codeline "this.locallist = local;" and write then into the console from the client the username will spammed into the server console ... so what did you after reading my answer ?

Comment: public service(Socket s,String user,int number,ArrayList<user> local) {
        this.s = s;
        this.user = user;
        this.number = number;
        locallist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(user u : local){
            locallist.add(u);
        }
    }

Comment: hmmm ... that should already work ... what exactly does now not work?
the only thing what should work now is that you can write into the client the username and after that it will spamm your username in your server-console

Comment: it does work the only problem now is that after each username the server class output looks like this : waiting for connexion
connected with /127.0.0.1:49999
username testeone usernumber 0
waiting for connexion
connected with /127.0.0.1:50018
username testetwo usernumber 0
username testetwo usernumber 0
waiting for connexion

Comment: so what exactly is here the problem?
if you just want the number fixed  declare the "int number = 0;" variable insteat of in the while-loop above the while
tell me what you exacly want ... i can't read your mind ... is it because your client connect to the server everytime you write in a username or what ?

Comment: i will change the post in order to have a general idea about the problem

Comment: I have changed my answer for you and seriosly next time don't change the whole question just because you got a completly new problem ... do a new question or ask in the comments for help ... my answer was valid and fixed actually the problem you described and not the whole thing which you know have